# How do I maintain camelCase when using D3 Attr

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code...

```
let row = svg.selectAll("div")
           .data(cleanData)
           .enter()
           .append("div")
           .attr("fxLayout", "row");
```

This works great except the `fxLayout` comes out `fxlayout`

Can I do this but maintain the case of the attribute?

**Per Comments**

I tried using the following...

```
>row.node().attributes
NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: fxlayout, length: 2}
>row.node().setAttribute("NewThen","123")
undefined
>row.node().attributes
NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: fxlayout, 2: newthen, length: 3}
```

So as you can see even accessing the DOM element appears to still set it wrong.

Comment: It most likely is correct. The dev tools tend to display the attribute names as all lower case. Try something like `d3.select("div").node().attributes`, which will show the camel case name.

Comment: BTW, your use of `.append()` is not correct. In D3, contrary to jQuery, you cannot append an element and set the class in one step. You need to do `.append("div").attr("class", "row")` or `.append("div").classed("row", true)`.

Comment: See my update, thanks for the idea

Comment: Have a look at [*"How can I set an Attribute with case-sensitive name in a javascript generated element"*](/q/28734628). Because you are dealing with HTML, your attributes will be dealt with as being case-insensitive. What is your `fxLayout` actually? It is definitely no standard HTML attribute.

Comment: Nope, it isn't standard, it is an Angular 2 directive for the new Material Flex Layout

Comment: I'm having this trouble with Firefox and `svg.attr("viewBox","0 0 100 100")`.  Chrome handles this fine, but Firefox really screws it up!

Comment: @micahphones I bet your svg element is in the wrong namespace but you should ask a new question rather than trying to piggy-back on this one.

Comment: @micahphones Did you actually read the question I linked to in my other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332299/how-do-i-maintain-camelcase-when-using-d3-attr#comment71818173_42332299)? It *exactly* describes your problem.

Comment: @altocumulus I did, and I've tried that and quite a few more things.  The reason I haven't created a new question yet is that I'm trying to isolate my issue.  Actually, the example in your answer runs fine for me on Firefox, yet I'm having issues with my own code.

The main difference between your example and my situation is that I'm using the shadydom polyfill, and my SVG is in a fake shadow DOM.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with it, but need to do more testing.

Comment: @altocumulus my issue turned out to be a bug in the shim I was using (native-shim), which replaced setAttribute with a function that lowercased attributes.  This was only affecting firefox in my case, so I naively blamed it on ff!

Comment: @micahphones Hm, looking at the shim, I am not yet convinced you found the real cause for your troubles. This might well be worth a question in its own right, but, since this is not your question, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @altocumulus, the shim has since been fixed! I was using a package that depended on an old version.